# Alignment lines in CameraX

Tags: android, android-camerax

I noticed a new feature on my Vanilla Android's (Pixel 5, Android 11) default camera app recently. There are these 2 lines (one yellow and one white) that help me line up my phone in 3d space. They remind me a bit of those levels with the bubble inside it.

Does CameraX support that natively yet? I want to incorporate it into a custom camera app. If CameraX does not support it natively is there an SDK around that will do the trick? I am having trouble finding much documentation for it or even what those lines are called.

This is for a customer request so the requirements are specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without camera. Simply get the accelerometer readings and draw the lines based on the x/y/z value. See: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion